# How to load a image from assets?

Tags: android, assets

i need to load a image from assets to avoid a froyo 2.2.2 bug resizing POT images in some particular cases. The way to avoid it is loading the image files from assets dir.

I'm trying to do with this:

```
String imagePath = "radiocd5.png";
AssetManager mngr = context.getAssets();
// Create an input stream to read from the asset folder
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = mngr.open(imagePath);
} catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace();}
    
//Get the texture from the Android resource directory
//InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.radiocd5);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
    //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

} finally {
    //Always clear and close
    try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

But i am getting NullPointerException on the line `is.close();`

i capture a FileNotFoundException: radiocd5.png, but that file is on my assets directory :S

What am i doing bad? The file is called `radiocd5.png` and it is on the `assets` directory

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can follow my tutorials on displaying data from Assets: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/ 
The sample with loading image and text to display.

I now added the relevant part of the provided link 
(in case of earthquake or something) ;-) Taifun

```
// load image
try {
    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: what error? please be clear, I try to help you as long as you provide me enough and good info.

Comment: i capture a FileNotFoundException: radiocd5.png, but that file is on my assets directory :S

Comment: a good practice, anytime you update resources, clean project and run again!

Comment: Shouldn't the input stream also be closed after the image load? After line 50 something.

Comment: could you please provide some of the code and directions in your stackoverflow answer. Link answers are discouraged especially that the other site might go down (earthqake or something you never know :P )

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the assets dir, put the file into /res/raw, and you can then access it using the following URI: `android.resource://com.your.packagename/" + R.raw.radiocd5`

Comment: i dont have raw directory, and i can't create it because this app will be generated automatically with our company generator, and can't create dirs

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    InputStream istr = this.context.getAssets().open(P.strImage);
    //set drawable from stream
    this.imgProduct.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(istr, null));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected String openImageInAssets(String imageName) {
    String encodedImageBase64 = "";
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream fileStream = null;
    try {
        fileStream = assetManager.open(imageName);
        if (fileStream != null) {
            // BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileStream, null, bfo);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileStream);
            // Convert bitmap to Base64 encoded image for web
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // to get image extension file name split the received
            int fileExtensionPosition = imageName.lastIndexOf('.');
            String fileExtension = imageName.substring(fileExtensionPosition+1);
            // Log.d(IConstants.TAG,"fileExtension: " + fileExtension);

            if (fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                // Log.d(IConstants.TAG,"fileExtension is PNG");
            } else if (fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                // Log.d(TAG,"fileExtension is JPG");
            }

            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            String imgageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            encodedImageBase64 = "data:image/png;base64," + imgageBase64;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return encodedImageBase64="";
    } finally {
        //Always clear and close
        try {
            if (fileStream != null) {
                fileStream.close();
                fileStream = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Log.d(TAG,"encodedImageBase64: " + encodedImageBase64);
    return encodedImageBase64;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version, inside a fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createrestaurant_layout, container, false);
    Resources res = getResources();
    img = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.img);
    AssetManager amanager = res.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream imageStream = amanager.open("restaurant.jpg");
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, imageStream);
        img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This process seems much simpler in iOS/UIKit or iOS/SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way

```
setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assets.open("photo.jpg")))
```