# Load Images from assets folder

Tags: java, android

I have an android application in which I have several images in assets folder. Now I want to make an array of that images. Now my problem is :- 
when our images are in drawable we can make an array like

```
int x[] = {
    R.drawable.ss,
    R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.sk,
    R.drawable.xx
};
```

and so on. how can i make an array of images same as above when my images are in assets folder. 
I want to make an array at class level.

Comment: you could do it with a String array with the filenames

Comment: use search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645268/how-to-load-a-image-from-assets

Answer (score 28):

You have to read image by image like below:

You can use AssetManager to get the InputStream using its open() method and then use decodeStream() method of BitmapFactory to get the Bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If your images are stored in image folder in assets directory then you can get the list of image as way

```
private List<String> getImage(Context context) throws IOException {
      AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
      String[] files = assetManager.list("image");   
      List<String> it = Arrays.asList(files);
      return it; 
}
```

Comment: I want to declare it at class level. Is this possible

Comment: then you need to get the context first then after you can get asset

Comment: can you explain more with example

Comment: I edited the code above if you want to use in class level then you should pass Context just like above but make sure that Conetx should be initialize first either with Activity or ApplicationContext

Answer (score 4):

```
 // load image from asset folder 
        try {
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            // set image to ImageView
            mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            return;
        }

  or you can create drawable array
    Drawable d []={d};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong meaning about drawables and assests. You can make array od "drawables", because all drawables have own ids in R (like R.dawable.ss), so you can use specified integer to get drawable if you have proper context.

Other way managing files like images is assests. If you want do manage images by theirs ids you must add this images do drawables. In other way, assests files must be managed like a simple files in dir.

You must get files from assets `AssetManager am=this.getAssets();` and then prepare file to read/write. If you have images you can do something like this:

```
try {    
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("009.gif"));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```