# Confusion about InputStream

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple app. I have a method for returning an `InputStream` and then I will bind this stream to an ImageView. But it doesn't work as always. There is no exception. What am I doing wrong. How can I make this code run?

```
String[] names;
Bitmap bmp;
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AssetManager am=getAssets();
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    try {
        names=am.list("myfiles");
        InputStream is=bitmapStream(names[1]);
        bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public InputStream bitmapStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = null;
    is = openFileInput(name);   
    return is;
}
```

Comment: What is happening? Is it not compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you're trying to load is not at the place were you try to load it from.

> ```
>   try {
>         String folder = "myfiles";
>         names=am.list(folder);
>         InputStream is= am.open(folder+"/"+names[0]);
>         bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
>         img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps can be null. I suggest using an asynchronous loading library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Answer (score 0):

Try loading a drawable from the inputStream. A similar question was answered here, it might help:
[How to load a image from assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645606/3664895)