# how can i use a picture for background of a button from assets? and how can i add different music in background for each layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, background, background-image, background-music

how can i use a picture for background of a button from assets?

```
android:background="@drawable/icon_none"
```

but in assets it's not working, i tried this code:

```
android:background="@assets/icons/icon_none"
```

its need source code or it could be fixed in layout.

and how can i add a different music played in background for each layout and add turn on and turn off button.
can anybody offer a source code for me to work on it or a site that teach source codes?

Comment: I think you can't load image directly from assert in xml, you need to load at run time using java code.

Comment: correct but i dont know how to do it :(

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645268/how-to-load-a-image-from-assets

Comment: thanks i am working on it but i didnt fully got it, its just the source code. how can i use it in layout for button.
and the link in accepted answer is didnt opened for me