# Reading images from asset and fill in the array

Tags: java, android, android-assets

I have a gallery 
I have some pictures in my gallery that there are in the drawable. like this first I put the into in Integer Array like this.

```
Integer stickers_big[] = { R.drawable.stck1, R.drawable.stck2,...}
```

and this my adapter :

```
    class stickersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;

    public stickersAdapter(FirstActivity act) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ctx = act;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return stickers_drawable.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(ctx);
        imageview.setImageResource(stickers_drawable[position].intValue());
        imageview.setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        return imageview;
    }

}
```

Now I want to put my images into assets . I do like this , I read my image name and then set it into my imagview. but I JUST read one image name. I dont know how to read the name of all my images and open them.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(ctx);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims = assetManager.open("stck1.png");

            // create drawable from stream
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

            // set the drawable to imageview
            imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

        }


        return imageview;
    }

}

How to read ALL of my images then open them?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create sub-folder in assets directory. use getAssets().list() for getting all file names from assets:

```
 String[] images =getAssets().list("images");
ArrayList<String> listImages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(images));

Now to set image in imageview you first need to get bitmap using image name from assets :

InputStream inputstream=mContext.getAssets().open("images/"
                                      +listImages.get(position));
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputstream, null);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: i have error in this line     String[] images =getAssets().list("images");

Comment: I put it in try and catch , and run it , but nothing show , my images dont show

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to put my images into assets .

At first keep your images into image folder and then use this way

```
 int imageResource = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/stck1".replace(".jpg", ""), null,ctx.getPackageName());
 imageview.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Comment: I want to put them in asset not drwable, I say it in my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645268/how-to-load-a-image-from-assets

Comment: @nsr please check above two links .hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this hierarchy in your assets folder

```
assets
 |__img1
 |__img2
 |__img3
```

you can get them like this

```
try {  
    String[] list = getAssets().list("");

    for(String img: list ){
        //do your stuff here
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

if you have sub-folder in assets, put its name in `list("sub_folder");`

You can get this list in your activity, if you are in fragment you will have to do `getActivity()getAssets().list("");`. Once you have list of your images name, you may pass it to you adapter and can use it in your `getView()` method w.r.t position.

Comment: where you want to get all the names which you have put in your assets. `list` will have all those names and you can loop them to get every single name.

Comment: Would you please take a look at Sandeep dhiman answer , Now in this way I can get image names easliy but my gallery dont show my picture