# Android Build fails when I change a .png

Tags: android, nativescript

I have a NativeScript Application with the directory 
`...\app\App_Resources\Android\`
where alle the images are stored (like `drawable-hdpi` etc.).

Whenever I change a picture (e.g. `...\app\App_Resources\Android\drawable-hdpi\icon.png` to another png I receive a mergeerror:

```
:generateF0F1F2F3DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1F2F3DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
:mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Did I miss something to do before? I converted the new .png from a .jpg, but that should not have impact (I could swear it worked already). The iOS-Version is running without any problems.

Edit: What I did:

I resized a jpg to the format of the old .png files and converted it into a .png, then inserted them and replaced the old .png-files by the new .png-files having the same size as the old ones have had.

So to be clear:

There was a file `...\app\App_Resources\Android\drawable-hdpi\icon.png` with the size 72x72 and I had a file

icon.jpg which I resized to 72x72 and converted it into icon.png.
Then I inserted it for the other picture, so now I have (again)

`...\app\App_Resources\Android\drawable-hdpi\icon.png` with the size 72x72 just displaying a slightly other picture.

My pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Jaz.jpg

What else do I have in that directory:

In my `...\app\App_Resources\Android` I have the AndroidManifest.xml and the app.gradle and some xml-stuff which should not impact any pictures.

Edit 2: If that matters: These images are the launch screen and the icon of the android app. Could it be that the manifest saves some metadata stuff and fails to merge it? Or do I need to adjust the .xml-files from the "values" and "values-21" folders?

Edit 3 ------------------

when I run tns debug android --log trace I get the following output:

```
15:25:01.117 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}) discarded: Crunching C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [QUIET] [system.out] Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): Crunching single PNG file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): -> QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT notify(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}): Crunching single PNG file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}) discarded: Crunching single PNG file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843):  Output file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): -> QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT notify(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}):        Output file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.118 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}) discarded:     Output file: C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): Done
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT out(Facade for 1223856843): -> QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT notify(QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png,
task={from=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png, to=C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1F2F3\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png},
future=com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@9c66ab1}): Done
15:25:01.119 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources FAILED
15:25:01.119 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 7.194 secs.
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.45 completed (0 in use)
15:25:01.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 26.976 secs, idle: 0.069 secs
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.123 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:25:01.124 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
15:25:01.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.126 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
15:25:01.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
15:25:01.128 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
15:25:01.130 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
15:25:01.131 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
15:25:01.132 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:25:01.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
...
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
15:25:01.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 70 more
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:268)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:410)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:154)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 77 more
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:264)
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 80 more
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:446)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.out(AaptProcess.java:284)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.out(AaptProcess.java:215)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$2.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:143)
15:25:01.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:25:01.136 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
15:25:01.136 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
15:25:01.136 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
```

Comment: You can't have jpg file inside the drawable folder

Comment: I meant png, edited it, ofc you are right :D

Comment: Hit this command in terminal of AS and check ERROR tag in buildLog.txt  `./gradlew :<your_project_folder_name>:mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources --debug > buildLog.txt --stacktrace`

Comment: @nitinkumarp android studio is not used when building NativeScript applications, all I use is the running emulator. Is this still working then?

Comment: <your_project_folder> is the name you see on Project tab in AS where your main source code reside.

Comment: Hit the above command from the root directory of your Project folder. <your_project_folder_name> would be the name of the directory where you have Main project src. Suppose your main src have directory name "app" then the command would be: `./gradlew :app:mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources --debug > buildLog.txt --stacktrace`

Comment: I cannot execute the /gradlew - command since my terminal cannot find that command. Is that a windows thing (that he does not find the command) or did I miss something on the installation? Still I ran it with a --log trace and posted an update, perhaps that is what you looked for?

Answer (score 1):

If the `drawable-hdpi` contains png files keep the same format in all files. This error is due to you have the same file with a different extension in the same folder. Check the resource files.

Comment: NativeScript applications are not developed inside Android Studio.

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya So you mean that I have two different pictures with the same name in my directory where the metadata are not the same? But if I check it there is only one picture for every name and I already tried cleaning the cache and readding the platform/rebuilding the project. What else could I try?

Comment: Readd the android platform, see if that helps.

Comment: @pkanev I already tried that, the outcome did not change. I also tried with another android Version

Comment: is it possible, that the Manifest compares the image with some other metadata? Since the pictures are the launchscreen and the app-icon.

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete all the cache of your previous builds from your project directory. This is common issue when changing image resources.

Although as @Vodet said, drawable folder works with .png and .xml resources, not .jpg. So if you necessarily want to use a .jpg resource, you want to make an assets folder at the same level as res folder in the project directory hierarchy and load .jpg from there. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645268/how-to-load-a-image-from-assets) for more detail.

Comment: You are right, i mean't a .png instead of a .jpg, my fault. I edited my question and described what I did.

Comment: I updated the error message, there seems to be a cache in the .gradle folder, but that pictures have nothing to do with my icons (at least that's what I see). I removed the .gradle folder but the outcome did not change. Can I clear the cache on another way?